# Previous employment history

Tags: background-check

I recently got a job offer for a company that I have really wanted to get into. The position that I had applied for is different from my current role of two years but the new role is going to be a role which I have 10 years of past experiences. In summary, I was trying to get back to a similar position that I was 2 years ago after realising that I don't really enjoy my current role.  And I manage to convince my new employer that my skillsets is still there after 2 years. My concern now is on the background check that is about to be conducted.  I have written in my resume that I have been in my current company for the past 2 Years when in fact I have been in 2 different companies over the 2 year period. I wasn't upfront about being in 2 different company over the 2 year period as I didn't want to appear that I was job hopping. The truth is, I was trying out a role I thought I might enjoy but it turns out to be not something I enjoy after trying out at 2 different companies. Now, after 2  years, am convinced is not for me. I know I should have been honest in my application but in my opinion my past 2 years experience is irrelevant for the new role I am about to take on, and hence it shouldn't really matter if the experience is from 1 or 2 companies.Is there anything I can do now before the background check begin? Should I come clean with my employment history ? What else can I do ?

Question is - can I call the pre-screening company to correct the details now or do I wait for them to find out and explain why later?

Comment: It is always better for them to find out about your lie from *you* than from a third-party (such as background check). I will make it even easier for you: 1. They are going to find out about your 2-jobs-thing anyway. 2. If they find out from the background check, they **will** withdraw the job offer. 3. If they find out from *you*, they **might** withdraw the offer **or** let you off one time in appreciation of your honesty. What do you think you should do?

Comment: um, what sort of background check is it? do you *know* what they are checking up on? sometimes a background check is just to make sure you're not a criminal...

Comment: i cannot give an answer as the question is on hold, but if i were you, i would just tell them that you messed up the CV you gave. don't say you lied - no no  no - just say that you messed up the formatting/editing of the CV. This is assuming that you didn't *verbally* tell them about the 2 year job - because then they'll know you're lying, and then nothing would help you. People can mess up CVs, just say you accidentally submitted one that  didn't have the right info.

Comment: @bharal She put the same info on the application as on the resume so I am curious to know how claiming that she made made the same inadvertent mistake on the resume as on the application - I am curious how that's going to work out

Comment: @bharal As Vietnhi Phuvan points out, the OP messed up both the CV and the application. Usually there is applicant's signature (in ink or digital) on the application. The OP needs to be responsible for that.

Comment: @scaaahu see below

Comment: @Vietnhi i do not know why you think that? OP only directly refers to the resume. in my reading, the OP uses the word "application" to refer to the resume submitted.

Comment: @bharal This is what I read: _I know I should have been honest in my application_. My interpretation is that the OP did not tell the truth on the application.

Comment: bharal "application" means "application". "resume"means "resume". The OP lied on both, so there is something for everyone :) I am suspecting that the OP mucked up the waters by downplaying the fact that he or she lied on the application.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't come clean, their background check is going to be a dud and if it's a dud, you are going to have to come up with a good explanation. Fast.

They're going to find out that the data in your application does not add up, so your choice is either you tell them before they hit the brick wall or you wait until they get back to you with the story in your application that doesn't add up. If you get proactive, you can to an extent shape perceptions. It's much harder to shape perceptions once the facts are on the front page.

You didn't want to be perceived as a job hopper but in order not to be perceived as a job hopper, you put yourself into a position where there is a pretty good chance that you'll be perceived as a liar. Personally, I'd rather come across as a job hopper than as a liar. A hundred times over. If I were to consider hiring you, the question in my mind is at what point can I say that you are telling me the truth?  Frankly, I'd rather hire someone who is clearly less qualified but who tells me the truth than someone who has all the qualifications but whom I can't trust. All organizations run on trust and there is no telling what happens when trust is breached.

Lying on a resume is nowhere as serious as lying on an application. And you lied on an application. You'll have to come up with your own narrative.

Comment: +1 For _Lying on a resume is nowhere as serious as lying on an application._